# listening on netcat works but not grep'able (or several other utilities)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pipeline, netcat

I'm testing some netcat udp shell tools and was trying to take output and send it through standard pipe stuff.  In this example, I have a netcat client which sends 'foo' then 'bar' then 'foo' with newlines for each attempt reading from the listener:

```
[root@localhost ~ 05:40:20 ]# exec 5< <(nc -d -w 0 -6 -l -k -u 9801)
[root@localhost ~ 05:40:25 ]# awk '{print}' <&5
foo
bar
foo
^C
[root@localhost ~ 05:40:48 ]# awk '{print}' <&5 | grep foo
^C
[root@localhost ~ 05:41:12 ]# awk '{print}' <&5 | grep --line-buffered foo
^C
[root@localhost ~ 05:41:37 ]#
[root@localhost ~ 05:44:38 ]# grep foo <&5
foo
foo
^C
[root@localhost ~ 05:44:57 ]#
```

I've checked the --line-buffered... and I also get the same behavior from 'od -bc', ie, nothing at all.  Grep works on the fd... but if I pipe that grep to anything (like od -bc, cut), I get the same (nothing).  Tried prefixing the last grep with stdbuf -oL to no avail.  Could > to file and then tail -f it, but feel like I'm missing something.

Update:
Appears to be something descriptor/order/timing related.  I created a file 'tailSource' and used this instead, which produced the same issue (no output) when I ran `echo -e "foo\nfoo\nbar\nfoo" >> tailSource`

```
[root@localhost shm 07:16:18 ]# exec 5< <(tail -n 0 -f tailSource)
[root@localhost shm 07:16:32 ]# awk '{print}' <&5 | grep foo
```

... and when I run without the '| grep foo', I get the output I'd expect.
(GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu))

Comment: It does appear to be something specific to either a) netcat, or b) the sequence/timing of i/o.  As a comment below mentions, replacing the source of fd-5 with a flatout stream of lines would work as I'd expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` is buffering when its output is not going to a terminal. If you have GNU awk, you can use its fflush() function to flush after every print

```
gawk '{print; fflush()}' <&5 | grep foo
```

In this particular case though, you don't need awk and grep, either will do.

```
awk /foo/ <&5
grep foo <&5
```

See [BashFAQ 9](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009) for more on buffering and how to work around it.

Comment: gosh.. I should have known.. thanks a bunch, that fixed my problem.  Have wondered about coproc usage and that link suggests it may be of value here.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth

```
$ exec 5< <(echo -e "foo\nbar\nfoo")
$ awk '{print}' <&5 | grep foo
```

prints

```
foo
foo
```

where as

```
$ exec 5< <(echo -e "foo\nbar\nfoo") 
$ awk '{print}' <&5 
foo 
bar 
foo 
$ awk '{print}' <&5
$
```

the second call does not output anything.

I think this is because the file descriptor is at its end and you need to rewind it, see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23727023/1705441) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838322/bash-read-write-file-descriptors-seek-to-start-of-file) question.

In order to use it, you could alternatively either capture it in a temporary file or perform the transformations in one line.