# how bash create a file which only accessed by current bash script process

Tags: linux, bash, shell, file, permissions

As I know, the bash script can create and write **file** to `disk path` or `/dev/shm`, but the file was accessed by `root` or other user. How can I set the file's permission that only accessed by current bash script process? And I will `rm` this **file** before `exit` the bash script.

Comment: Maybe you can redirect a file to a given descriptor number, delete the file, and then use that descriptor with redirection...

Comment: @Shawn THX, I will try it.

Comment: But even that won't stop `root` to get to see it / its content if they set their mind to it.

Comment: Setting file permissions to 600 will stop all users except root. In general, stopping `root` needs a lot of very special actions. Selinux has been proposed (but I've never seen a  water-tight solution), in the past SeOS and Autosecure could do this. But limiting root is a bad idea. Limiting access to root is a better idea.

Comment: @VictorLee : You can't set permissions by PID. Even if you give user permissions only, another process running by you may manipulate the file. The usual trick is - in addition to restrict the permissions -  to choose a file name based on your PID, because no other process running at that time can have the same PID. Example: `touch my_file.$$`. At least accidentally overwriting this file by another process under your ID is then not so likely, but of course not impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect a filename to a given descriptor number, and delete the file, and then access it through the descriptor:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

name=$(mktemp)
exec {fd}<>"$name"
rm -f "$name"
echo foo >&$fd
cat </dev/fd/$fd
```

Using a descriptor that's been opened for both reading and writing with `<>` is tricky in `bash`, see [Bash read/write file descriptors — seek to start of file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3838322/9952196) for the logic behind that `cat` line at the end.

If you've never seen the `{name}<>filename` style redirection before, it automatically assigns an unused descriptor to the file and stores its number in `$name`.

Comment: This'll make it harder for any other process to access the file, but not impossible. For example, in Linux a root process could reach it at /proc/yourPID/fd/fdnum.

Comment: @GordonDavisson As pointed out in comments on the top level question, stopping root from accessing it is pretty much impossible.